# Limit rotation angles for Quaternion

Tags: unity, rotate

I have a short snippet that's rotating the meshes of the wheels as I'm driving forward, but it's also rotating wheels to match the direction I'm turning, and I wish to turn this off completely.

```
        Quaternion quat;
        Vector3 position;
        m_WheelColliders[i].GetWorldPose(out position, out quat);
        m_WheelMeshes[i].transform.position = position;
        m_WheelMeshes[i].transform.rotation = quat;
```

How would I lock what angles I don't want the wheel meshes rotating?

Comment: [steerAngle](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WheelCollider-steerAngle.html) I'm new to this type of colliders, but you might want to try clamping this value. But also I don't know how wheel colliders rotate, is it by force inside physics engine or manually. If manually, you could try Mathf.Clamp() values before assigning them.

Comment: Need to see more of your code to answer this